# how to make the arrow keys and space bar not force my webpage down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built a game and i am using the arrow keys to move and space bar to shoot and it keeps forcing it down to the bottom of the web page every time i hit the down key or space bar
is there any way to modify the CSS to make it focus on the game div tag and not scroll???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are failing to cancel the event. If it's an inline event, just `return false;` at the end of it. If it's done with `addEventListener`, call `Event.preventDefault()` and `return false;`.

Comment: +1. Here's a jsFiddle as an example (You would need to handle preventing default for the correct keycodes). http://jsfiddle.net/hCRpC/

Comment: thank you that helped alot its not scrolling any more it works great